# How to completely disable floppy in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, floppy

So I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and now I see `Floppy` in my `Home Folder tree` how do I remove it?

what I did since Ubuntu 12.04 is:

- Edit `/etc/fstab` to remove reference to floppy.
- Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` and add this line at the end:  `blacklist floppy`
- Run: `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- Run: `sudo update-grub`
- Restarted the system.

I checked `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` it contains `blacklist floppy` like it was before the upgrade but now I can see floppy in my Home Folder tree. Is there something else I need to change in 14.04?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Problem solved! Found the solution on Ubuntu 14.04 in terminal run:

1. `echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf`
2. `sudo rmmod floppy`
3. `sudo update-initramfs -u`

works right away.

Comment: Doesn't work on my 14.04 system....
~$ sudo rmmod floppy
rmmod: ERROR: Module floppy is in use

Comment: @Jebeld17 did you unmount it and blacklist it first? This workaround works on my system right away. And this answer solved my problem, if you experience issues with something else you should consider creating your own question.

Comment: I had this issue with Ubuntu 14.04 on a VMware workstation 10. This was the only one solution i've found that solve the problem.

Comment: Seems to have worked on my 16.04 server system on VMWare ESXi host.

Comment: to unmount floppy -  `sudo umount /dev/fd0`

Comment: it's to *unmount* but the question states to *remove / disable* the device.

Comment: @JoKeR You need to unmount the floppy first (if mounted), then rmmod the kernel module.